Iterate through a ReadDir and append file names to an array in Rust
I am trying to use the fs::read_dir() and iterate through the results and append all file names to an array. Something like this, except this isn't working:
let mut result: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
for i in fs::read_dir(directory).iter(){
    result.append(i);
}

I have tried quite literally anything I could find on the internet, but I'm quite new to Rust, and I don't really know what I'm doing.
NOTE: The directory parameter needs to be a type of string, since I'm working with Tauri, and TypeScript/JavaScript only has regular string, and not some other crazy type, which I could imagine Rust having.

Simple example:
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let mut result: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for i in fs::read_dir(".").unwrap() {
        let i = i.unwrap().path();
        let file_name = i.file_name().and_then(OsStr::to_str).unwrap();
        result.push(file_name.to_string());
    }

    dbg!(result);
}

append() only make sense when you merge two collections. Use push(). read_dir() return an Result, you need first to check the result to use the Iterator.

I wonder why every element in the iterator itself is of type Result so that unwrap needs to be called for every i in the fs::read_dir() result?
What errors do I have to be prepared for on single file level?

@dfsg76 a lot of error could happen, dir become inaccessible, corrupt entry, some weird thing probably.
